# How can I get the all the tag data with each task from the asana api?

Tags: asana

Currently I can get the tag id through opt_fields when getting a list of all tasks, which was not listed as an option, so my question is, is there anyway to get more than just the id back?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use more value for tags in opt_fields:

Get ID    - tags,
Get Name  - tags.name,
Get Color - tags.color
and etc.

Simple: ?opt_fields=tags,tags.name,tags.color

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!  I was honestly expecting to have to pull all the id's and compare to the ones attached to each task.

Comment: At Asana is limited to 100 requests per minute. This method will allow you to get more information per minute from Asana. I'm glad I helped you.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly why I was hoping this was a possibility.  Thanks again!